# Add extra context to django generic views

Tags: django, django-views, django-1.5

I would like to add the username of the user on pages like change_password. 
I don't think I can pass the username as extra context for in the url like that:

> url(r'^password_change/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', ),'extra_context':{'user_name': 'alexis'})

because I need to change 'alexis' to resquest.user.get_username() and I don't have access to the resquest.
I also tried to create a custom view but it doesn't work:

> from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change_done
>   def my_password_change(request):
>
> > return password_change_done(request,'password/password_change_form.html','extra_context':{'user_name': 'alexis'})

Thank you in advance for any input.
Alexis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username of the currently logged-in user should already be available in the template via `{{ user.username }}` (if using the context processor [`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) - which is highly recommended).

Comment: Not quite right. The auth processor is enabled by default (unlike the request one) but it makes `user` available directly, not via `request`.

Comment: Im wondering about something, I use '{{ user.username }}' in my templates and the display of the name is not consistant, sometime it's appears and sometimes it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: @AlexisBenoist You should just be careful if maybe one of your views specifies an object in the context that is also called _user_. Otherwise it should always be the logged-in user, except if you're not logged in, then it is an instance of `AnonymousUser`.